# KnockoutJs não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, knockoutjs

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.2.0.js'></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Já experimento colocar o `ko.applyBindings` para o final do html? Acredito que no momento em que ele é executado, os dois `input's` ainda não foram renderizados, e ai ele não encontra os elementos para fazer o `binding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o ko.applyBindings no final da pagina ou dentro do

$(function(){

});

Do JQUERY.

No seu caso, faça deste modo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.2.0.js'></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>


<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName"/></p>

</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Paulo";
    this.lastName = "Sousa";
}


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
```